# What geometric properties do properties of ell-adic Galois representations imply? 

Tags: arithmetic-geometry, galois-representations

This is the converse question to [an earlier question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17993/). More precisely,

Let $X/K$ be a curve(or variety) over a global field $K$. We consider the Galois representation obtained by the absolute Galois group $G_K$ acting on $H_{et}^i(X_{/\bar K}, \mathbb{Q}_\ell)$.

Do properties of this representation, such as "unramified at a place $v$", semistable, de Rham, crystalline, Hodge-Tate, and so on and so forth, imply some geometric properties about $X_{/K}$? (I must confess that I know the proper definition of only the first property in this list, but I nevertheless put in the whole list from the original question for good measure.)

If so, please give examples.

Comment: The original question was asked by norondion. To him/her: I hope you will forgive me for asking similar question, since imitation is the sincerest form of flattery.

Answer (score 11):

The converse is false. See the lecture notes by Chandan Singh Dalawat at http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0605326, which give some examples of varieties over finite extensions of $\mathbb{Q}_p$ whose $\ell$-adic cohomology is unramified for $\ell \ne p$ and crystalline at $\ell = p$, but the variety does not have good reduction.

Comment: Neron-Ogg-Schaferevich says that for abelian varieties, the Galois representation on H^1 controls the reduction in the obvious way, but as David says it's too much to hope for in general.

Comment: Some explicit examples of curves have been provided by Qing Liu (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/10463/a-nice-variety-without-a-smooth-model/11302#11302)) One can also write down Châtelet surfaces over $\mathbb{Q}_p$ which have bad reduction and yet the $p$-adic étale cohomology is *unramified*   (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/416/existence-of-smooth-models/10264#10264)

Comment: If $E$ is an elliptic curve with good reduction over $\mathbb Q_p$, and one takes a non-trivial torsor $P$ over $E$, then $P$ will not admit a model with good reduction, yet $H^1(P_{\overline{\mathbb Q}_p})$ and $H^1(E_{\overline{\mathbb Q}_p}, \mathbb Q_{\ell})$ coincide,
and hence $H^1(P_{\overline{\mathbb Q}_p},\mathbb Q_{\ell})$ will be unramified (if $\ell \neq p$) or crystalline (if $\ell = p$).  
(This example is noted in the reference provided by David, but seems fundamental enough to be worth spelling out here.)

Comment: I should also have noted that "the reference provided by David" is in fact written by Chandan Singh Dalawat!

Comment: As, indeed, should I.

Comment: The problem with curves is that $H^1$ represents only the abelian part of $\pi_1$, so you lose some information on the geometry of the curve. There exists however an anabelian analogue by considering the representation in Out$(\pi_1)_{\ell}$. Then one has a good reduction criterium à la Néron-Ogg-Shafarevich. See Theorem 3.2 in T. Oda: A Note on Ramification of the Galois Representation on the Fundamental Group of an Algebraic Curve, II, Journal of Number Theory
Volume 53, Issue 2, August 1995, Pages 342-355. 