# Is there a deep relationship between models and étale cohomology ?  If so, why, and is it made precise somewhere ?

Tags: etale-cohomology, ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Let me recall two theorems :

> Let $K$ be a field, $\overline{K}$ be
>   a separable closure of $K$ with
>   absolute Galois group
>   $G_K:=Gal(\overline{K}/K)$, and let
>   $\ell$ be a prime that is different
>   from $char(K)$. Let $X$ be a
>   $K$-scheme that is separated and of
>   finite type.  The $\ell$-adic
>   cohomology groups with proper support
>   $H^i_c(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$.
>
> They are finite dimensional
>   $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ vector spaces and
>   are zero for $i>2\cdot \text{dim}(X)$
>   and $G_K$ acts (via monodromy, as the fundamental group) continuously on them,
>   so that for each $g\in G_K$, the trace
>   $$\text{Tr}(g,H^\ast_c(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}))=\sum(-1)^i\text{Tr}(g,H^i_c(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}))$$
>   is defined. This $\ell$-adic number is
>   in fact an $\ell$-adic integer.
>
> Write $K$ as the inductive limit of
>   its $\mathbb{Z}$-sub-algebras of
>   finite type. A *model* of $X/K$ over
>   such a subring $R$ is a scheme
>   $\mathcal{X}$ that is separated and of
>   finite type over $S=Spec(R)$ such that
>   $\mathcal{X}\times_{S} Spec(K)= X$.  A
>   model of $X/K$ is essentially unique
>   ``up to shrinking'': two models
>   $\mathcal{X}_1/R_1$  and
>   $\mathcal{X}_2/R_2$ become isomorphic
>   over some $S=Spec(R)$ with $R\supseteq
> > R_1,R_2$ [EGA4,section 8].
>
> ***Theorem 1*** [Serre, 2004]  Under the above notations and assumptions, for a
>   positive integer $n$, the following
>   conditions are equivalent:
>
> - There exists a model $\mathcal{X}/S$ of $X/K$ having the
>     following property: for all points
>     $s=Spec(k')\to S$ with value in a
>     finite field $k'$ of characteristic
>     different from $\ell$, we have
>     $$|\mathcal{X}(s)|\equiv 0\text{ }(
>   > \text{ mod } \ell^n)$$
> - For all $g\in G_K$, we have $$\text{Tr}(g,H_c^\ast(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}))\equiv
>   > 0\text{ }( \text{ mod } \ell^n)$$
>
> This result is published in Illusie's note *Miscellany on traces in $\ell$-adic cohomology* from 2005.

On the other hand, let me recall Saito's approach (1987) to stable reduction of curves :

> let $C$ be a curve proper and smooth over $K=Frac(R)$, $R$ a complete DVR with algebraically closed residual field $k(R)$ of characteristic $p>0$.
>
> ***Theorem 2*** [Stable reduction] Let $C$ be a geometrically irreducible proper smooth curve over $K$ of genus $g\geq 2$.  Then there exists a finite separable extension $K'/K$ such that $C_{K'} = C\times_K K'$ admits a *stable model* over the integral closure $R'$ of $R$ in $K'$.  I.e., $C_{K}$ is the generic fibre of some $C_m/R$ which is proper, flat, separated of finite type of relative dimension 1 whose geometric fibres are stable curves (i.e., they are reduced, connected, with only ordinary double points as singularities, and each connected component intersects the others in at least 3 points).
>
> Saito's proof essentially shows that whether a curve admits a stable model (i.e., $K'=K$) is encoded by the representation $H^1(C_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ of $Gal(\overline{K}/K)$ :
>
> ***Theorem*** [Saito] Let $C$ be a geometrically irreducible proper smooth curve over $K$ of genus $g\geq 2$.  The following conditions are equivalent :
>
> - $C$ admits a stable model
> - the action of inertia $I_K$ on $H^1(C_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ is unipotent.
>
> I refer you to Abbes' article in *Courbes semi-stables et groupe fondamental en géométrie algébrique*, Birkhäuser (1998) for a discussion of Saito's proof.

***Question*** Do you know of other theorems of a similar flavor ?  Are there general remarks on why such results might not be surprising ?

Answers I'm looking for would : state other theorems of a similar flavor, or explain why such theorems shouldn't be surprising (i.e., by heuristic explainations of how étale cohomology naturally detects such aspects of geometry).

Comment: This is not at all an answer to your question, but a friend of mine suggested a possible model-theoretic proof of the infinitude of Mersenne primes some time last year. It seemed to reduce the problem to a harder model theory problem (hence the fact that this proof was nver finished.)

It seems to be a similar sort of thing: there's a nice model theoretic way of looking at a problem, and a lot of the work has already been done by model theorists somewhere.

Comment: Could you be more specific about what is confusing you?  Is your question really just "cohomology is powerful! What's with that?"  Also, you're using the term "model theory" in a very misleading way.  There is a branch of mathematics called ["model theory"](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CAgQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FModel_theory&ei=2LDZS7_lEIO88gaD7N1Z&usg=AFQjCNFUrBFNM9iOLgNrs8pHCYZUdQaMIw&sig2=SW-iP98shXKY6x44j8A3gQ) that has nothing to do with this post.

Comment: I think the sense in which you are using the word "model" is unrelated to what "model-theory" usually means... In any case, the result of Saito goes back to the Neron-Ogg-Shafarevich criterion for good reduction of abelian varieties and Grothendieck's criterion for semi-stable reduction and is perhaps not really surprising once one takes those results into consideration.

Comment: OK, 'model theory' dropped.  In any case it's clear what is meant by models in both cases.


Comment: A closely related question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18006

Comment: The result of Serre seems to just be a consequence of the Grothendieck-Lefschetz trace formula plus some base change theorems. For simplicity, let's say that $X/K$ is $K$-smooth (you can probably avoid this using stronger results, e.g. Deligne's Weil II). Then given some $\mathcal{X}/S$, we can shrink $S$ so that we can assume without loss of generality that $\mathcal{X}/S$ is smooth. Then the smooth and proper base change theorems say that we can identify $H^i(X_{K^s}, \underline{\mathbf{Q}_\ell})$ with $H^i_c(\mathcal{X}_{\overline{k(x)}}, \underline{\mathbf{Q}_\ell)$.

Comment: Now, the trace of the Frobenius automorphism generating $\overline{k(s)}/k(s)$ on $H^i(\mathcal{X}_{\overline{k(x)}}, \underline{\mathbf{Q}_\ell)}$ is related to $|\mathcal{X}(s)|$ by the Grothendieck-Lefschetz trace formula. We can lift this to an element of $G_K$ (think of the case where $S = \mathrm{Spec} \mathscr{O}_K$), and the isomorphism coming from the base change theorems respects traces of elements of the Galois group, so we win.

Comment: BTW, the base change theorems are the basic reason why good reduction implies unramified Galois action (the converse is harder of course); compatibility of the base change isomorphisms with Galois shows us that inertia (the kernel of the restriction map on Galois groups) acts trivially.